# Recarga automática con Gulp y Live-Reload

Tags: javascript, nodejs, gulp

Buenos días, el navegador no me esta recargando el proyecto con gulp-liveReload + la extensión para chromer, 
mi pagacke.json es:

```
 {
"name": "davidvpino",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "proyecto",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "David Vásquez Pino",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
"gulp-watch": "^4.3.6"
 }
}
```

y este es mi gulpfile.js con la task creada

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function(){
      livereload.listen();
      gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', livereload.changed);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

en la terminal me sale como si estuviera vigilando y me dice que se realizo el reload, pero en el navegador no pasa nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sera problema con el código, o de la extención?

Comment: Hola David, te recomiendo una mirada a BrowserSync.  https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/

Comment: Que maravilla *-* muchas gracias!!!, si me funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [reload](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload#livereloadreloadfile) en lugar del método [changed](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload#livereloadchangedpath)

Este método te actualizará la página completa. Quedaría de esta forma

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function(){
      livereload.listen();
      gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', function() {
         livereload.reload();
      });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Lo anterior no te funcionará si tu fichero **no** se llama `index.html`, así que si este es el caso debería quedar así

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('watch', function(){
      livereload.listen();
      gulp.watch('./*.html').on('change', function(event) {
         livereload.reload(event.path);
      });
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Mira la propiedad [path](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#eventpath) del evento changed de gulp.watch

Comment: Genial Gracias por tu apoyo :D, me funciono también este cambio, mil gracias!!